# Dates get colored in firefox not in ie

Tags: javascript

is there an alternative for `elem.style.color` because it doesnt render a different color in IE, only in firefox and in other browsers the code renders...

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wboco/dp4j4/)
 works in firefox, not in IE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139560/element-style-color-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var dateArray = dateElement.split("-");
        var prevTime = new Date(dateArray);
```

Since you have dates already in the standard format (YYYY-MM-DD), just pass it in.

```
prevTime = new Date(dateElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with styles, `diffInDays` returns `NaN` which is not comparable.

```
NaN < 0  -> false
NaN > 0  -> false
NaN == 0 -> false
```